# C# Template parameter as a template interface

Tags: c#, java, templates

I am trying to translate this piece of code from Java to C# and I am having trouble finding the correct synthax

Java:

```
public class MyClass<T extends IMyInterface<T>>
```

My attempt at translating into C#:

```
public class MyClass<T, U> where T: IMyInterface<U>
```

If I do `public class MyClass<T> where T: IMyInterface<T>` , there is no compile error at the class declaration, but I cannot figure out how to use the class.

More specifically, I have an interface `IPoint<T>`, which is implemented by class `EuclideanPoint:IPoint<EuclideanPoint>`. Also, I have a templated class `Clusterer<U>`, which should not care about the template parameter of the interface, it should only make sure that U is of type IPoint.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a class that will implement IMyInterface ?

Comment: public class MyClass<T> :IMyInterface<T> ?

Comment: No, I am not trying to implement an interface. I am trying to use e templated interface as a type parameter for a templated class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the C# equivalent of the Java would just be:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
```

One type parameter in the Java, one in the C#.

How you use the class will depend on what `IMyInterface<T>` is and what implements it. For example, if it were `IEquatable<T>` instead, you could create a `MyClass<int>` because `int` implements `IEquatable<int>`.

Comment: I tried this version, but when I try to do this: MyClass<IMyInterface<T>> c = new MyClass<IMyinterface<T>>(), I get something like "There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IMyInterface<T>' to 'IMyInterface<IMyInterface<T>>'", where T is another template parameter

Comment: @ratzinho: No, that's right - because it could be something like `class Foo : IMyInterface<Bar>` which doesn't satisfy the contract. It would really help if you could explain what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Your hint was very helpful. I managed to do this: MyContainerClass<T> where T: IMyInterface<T> and then, inside MyContainerClass, I instantiated the class like this: MyClass<T> c = new MyClass<T>()

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass<T> where T: IMyInterface<T>
```

looks good.

If you have

```
 class MySecondClass : IMyInterface<MySecondClass>
 {

 }
```

then you can use

```
 MyClass<MySecondClass> obj = new MyClass<MySecondClass>();
```